# Should `drain` event be registered before the result of the write is available

Tags: node.js, node-streams

I have this snippet of code:

```
const file = fs.createWriteStream('./test.txt');
let written = true;

// handler is added before even an attempt to write is made
file.on('drain', function () {
    written = true;
    console.log('drained');
});

const interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (Date.now() - time > 10000) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    if (written) {
        written = file.write(new Array(1000000).join('z'));
    }
}, 100);
```

I'm wondering if that a standard practice to add handler even an attempt to write is made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of using `file.on('drain')` listener you set up general listener to drain event of your stream. 
Notice: This listener will be removed after closing of writable stream.

Generally that code will work proper, but most common practice in Node.js is to use `stream.once('drain')` handler for each case of internal buffer exceeding. That approach is covered in `Node.js` documentation for [Event: 'drain'](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_drain):

```
function writeOneMillionTimes(writer, data, encoding, callback) {
    var i = 1000000;
    write();
    function write() {
        var ok = true;

        do {
            i -= 1;
            if (i === 0) {
                // last time!
                writer.write(data, encoding, callback);
            } else {
                // see if we should continue, or wait
                // don't pass the callback, because we're not done yet.
                ok = writer.write(data, encoding);
            }
        } while (i > 0 && ok);

        if (i > 0) {
            // had to stop early!
            // write some more once it drains
            writer.once('drain', write);
        }
    }
}
```